# Linux kernel aes encryption/decryption

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am using this sample example to do some AES encryption/decyption inside a module. All the calls pass successfully but the decrypted text is not same as the plain text.

```
[ 4703.053265] encrypting -> plain: bb 2b d7 fb fc c6 0c f6 82 92 cd e1 62 2f 9f 95  .+..........b/..
[ 4703.053277] encrypted: 91 1c 91 51 3c 22 77 dd 82 b4 b7 52 c7 95 af 18  ...Q<"w....R....
[ 4703.053280] Encryption triggered successfully
[ 4703.053290] decrypting -> encrypted: 91 1c 91 51 3c 22 77 dd 82 b4 b7 52 c7 95 af 18  ...Q<"w....R....
[ 4703.053295] decrypted: 31 81 92 38 37 da ac 6c 1b fd 4e 86 a1 1b 06 26  1..87..l..N....&
[ 4703.053297] Decryption triggered successfully
```

Source at :
https://kernel.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-samples/crypto-API.html#code-example-for-symmetric-key-cipher-operation

Any hint in right direction would be appreciated !

Comment: Log the key and IV used both for encryption and decryption and the problem will probably become obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much.I was passing a pointer to IV and it  was getting modified while encryption !

Answer (score -2):

Storing key and iv in the caller and passing a copy of it to encryption and decryption call works fine.